# RDBMS: Calculate and print the return date, return month, and return year

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rdbms

You went to video store and rented a dvd that is due in 3 days from the rental date. Input the rental date , rental month, and rental year. Calculate and print the return date, return month, and return year.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
         CREATE PROCEDURE 
        get_data(rental date IN DATE , 
         rental _month IN VARCHAR(20) , rental_year IN 
         VARCHAR(20))
          IS
           BEGIN
              dbms_output.put_line(rental_date+3 || "--" 
               ||rental_month ||"---"||rental_year);
             END;
                  /

     BEGIN
         SELECT get_data(&date,&month,&year) from dual;
     END;
       /
```

work around with this change the logic for the dates on adding 3 if month/year gets changed to next month/year.